# ID based translation in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, translation, qt5

To use [ID based translation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/linguist-id-based-i18n.html) you have to use `qsTrId` instead of `qsTr`. While this works in QML files, C++ does not offer a function or macro `trId` (only `tr`).

But apparently those two shouldn't be mixed:

> Note: You must use only plain-text-based or only text-ID-based functions in one application. If you mix them, you will end up with an incomplete set of texts to be translated.

How do I use ID based translation in the C++ parts of my application?

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate function is `qtTrId`. See [Id based translations](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtInternationalization#43b304ead4174986c238cb4e0c4d5cb0).